# Query github user access based on repository

Tags: git, github, github-api

Here is my issue, I want to restrict users except a few to push to master.

Now, to do that I am planning to implement a pre-push hook which will do the following:

- Get the github account username based on the ssh-keys in place or via https when passed. This may be done via accessing Github’s Rest API with CURL.
- Then have a config file to compare the username obtained from the Rest API with the one from config file. If it returns true then push to master or else reject.

Answer (score 0):

The main drawback I see in the pre-push nook approach is that, I would have committed all my changes locally, before attempting a push. Then I realize I don't have the permission to push to say repo, causing me to do some re-work to get my changes to the right branch. Eventually, someone else will need to merge my work into master.

If you don't mind the overhead of managing another repository, you can fork your repository, and store all the non-master branches in the new repository. Now you can set up permitted users as collaborators in your "master" repository, containing just the master branch. Commits in the non-master repository can be submitted to the master repository as pull requests.

Comment: Well, I get the drawback, but thats why I only want to restrict it to the master branch rather then the repo. Basically its a user check to see if the user trying to push to master is in my list, if not then he/she will be rejected. For me forking repo's seems like a overhead to me.

Comment: One way or the other, you have to maintain something. If you find maintaining a config file with (many?) users acceptable, you can give it a try. Not sure how you will implement that though.